# How to use f-strings or format in except block?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, string-formatting, f-string

Trying to write a formatted message in the except block to potentially show the user their entered input and why it's incorrect.

```
try:
    rows = int(input("How many rows of odd numbers? >"))
    zero = 10 / rows
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
    print(f"{rows} is not a valid answer.")
```

This however gives me this error:

```
NameError: name 'rows' is not defined
```

Anyway to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an error because `rows` is still not defined when the exception is raised, but you could do something like:

```
rows = input("How many rows of odd numbers? >")
try:
    zero = 10 / int(rows)
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
    print(f"{rows} is not a valid answer.")
```

Comment: For better clarity, don't put statements that you don't expect to raise an exception in the `try` block. That is, you can move `rows = input("How many rows of odd numbers? >")` out of the `try` block.

Comment: @blhsing I agree with your statement. Edited.