# Gracefully Handle Exception from raw user input wrapped in an int function

Tags: python

Consider the function below:

```
def user_input():
    try:
        a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print(f"\n{a} is invalid.\n")
    else:
        return a
```

This doesn't handle exceptions gracefully but instead results in the following error if the user enters a non-number:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'v' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`

But if I do this:

```
a = input("Enter an integer: ")
try:
    a = int(a)
except ValueError:
    print(f"\n{a} is invalid.\n")
else:
    print(a)
```

It works as can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240892/how-to-use-f-strings-or-format-in-except-block). But I really want to wrap the input function in the int function so as to do the conversion directly and still gracefully handle exceptions from user input. Is there any alternative to this? Or must I use the input and int functions separately to get my desired result?

Comment: What should happen if input was invalid? How should the code proceed?

Comment: The larger code is in a while loop. If input is invalid, it should print the message in the except block and allow the user to try again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: The **"Encapsulating it All in a Function"** part of accepted answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: No it doesn't. I want to print the invalid input the user entered using f-strings as seen in my except block.

Comment: Then just change the error response. The general idea fits all your requirements.

Comment: Does that suggest it is impossible to print the invalid literal entered by the user in the error message using this method?

Comment: Just split assignment and `int` conversion like you did in your 2nd code block.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is due to the scope of the variable a within your `user_input()` function. When an exception occurs inside the `try` block during the `int()` conversion, the variable `a` is never assigned a value, leading to the `UnboundLocalError` when you attempt to reference it in the `except` block.

To handle this situation gracefully and avoid the `UnboundLocalError`, you should `initialize` a with a default value before the try block. You can try the following:

```
def user_input():
    a = None  # Initialize 'a' with a default value
    try:
        a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print(f"\n{a} is invalid.\n")
    else:
        return a
```

Comment: If a user enters a non-number, your solution will print `None is invalid.` but what I want to print is `{a} is invalid.` Showing the invalid literal entered by the user.

Comment: But you want to wrap the input function in the int function which is contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `a` is not defined in your favorite version.

If you can avoid printing the problematic input (as seen below), you can use your first version. Since the error is raised inside the int() function, `a` does not exist and cannot be reported in your error message.

```
try:
    a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
except ValueError:
    print(f"Your input is invalid.\n")
else:
    print(a)
```

Obviously, you can merge both versions:

```
try:
    a = input("Enter a number: ")
    a = int(a)
except ValueError:
    print(f"{a} is invalid.\n")
else:
    print(a)
```

Comment: It is defined though. `a = input("Enter an integer: ")`. `try` clause does not create a new scope.

Comment: no, the code fails before a was assigned anything... because the code does not reach the assignment since it fails inside. If you write each command in a separate line and use the debugger, you will see that it does not execute the assignemnt... this is why you cannot reference a in the exception clause